# How to scrape part of a page node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm fairly new to coding and I don't understand why my code isn't working. It is suppose to output `"Dominus Empyreus"`
Though it only outputs `[]`

Here is my current code:

```js
const axios = require('axios'); 
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); 
 
const extractLinks = $ => [ 
    ...new Set( 
        $('.border-bottom item-name-container') // Select pagination links 
            .toArray() // Convert cheerio object to array 
    ), 
]; 
 
axios.get('https://www.roblox.com/catalog/21070012/Dominus-Empyreus').then(({ data }) => { 
    const $ = cheerio.load(data); // Initialize cheerio 
    const stuff = extractLinks($); 
 
    console.log(stuff); 
    // ['Dominus Empyreus'] 
});
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use the full selector path to the element directly that you want to scrape from a web page as such:

```js
const axios = require('axios'); 
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); 

const extractLinks = $ => [
    ...new Set( 
        $("#item-container > div.remove-panel.section-content.top-section > div.border-bottom.item-name-container > h1") // Select pagination links 
            .toArray() // Convert cheerio object to array 
    ), 
]; 

axios.get('https://www.roblox.com/catalog/21070012/Dominus-Empyreus').then(({ data }) => { 
    const $ = cheerio.load(data); // Initialize cheerio 
    const stuff = extractLinks($);

    console.log(stuff[0].children[0].data);
    // ['Dominus Empyreus'] 
});
```

A quick and simple way of obtaining a full selector path is using the F12 developer's console on your browser, right-click the element -> Copy -> Copy Selector.

[image: img]

In this case, the selector for this `<h1>` element is:

```css
#item-container > div.remove-panel.section-content.top-section > div.border-bottom.item-name-container > h1
```

The one thing to note is that this solution will only work if the selector path is the exact same on every page you wish to scrape.

Answer (score 2):

This is the element you are trying to select.

> ```
> <div class="border-bottom item-name-container">
> ```

You have written:

> ```
> .border-bottom item-name-container
> ```

Which consists of:

- A class selector (for `class="border-bottom"`)
- A descendant combinator
- A type selector (for `<item-name-container>`)

What you need is:

- A class selector (for `class="border-bottom"`)
- Another class selector (for `class="item-name-container"`)
- **No** descendant combinator (because you are targeting two features of the same element, not one element that is a descendant of the other).

Such:

```
.border-bottom.item-name-container
```